# Tensorflow Eager: Store and Restore Trainable variables

Tags: tensorflow

I've written a custom model with Tensorflow Eager(similar to this [example](https://github.com/ZhuanZhiCode/TensorFlow-Eager-Execution-Examples/blob/master/examples/Models/convolutional_neural_network.py)). I want to store/restore just my trainable variables - something similar to the following non-eager logic. How can I do this within Eager?:

```
def store(self, sess_var, model_path):
    if model_path is not None:
        saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
        save_path = saver.save(sess_var, model_path)
        print("Model saved in path: %s" % save_path)
    else:
        print("Model path is None - Nothing to store")

def restore(self, sess_var, model_path):
    if model_path is not None:
        if os.path.exists("{}.index".format(model_path)):
            saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
            saver.restore(sess_var, model_path)
            print("Model at %s restored" % model_path)
        else:
            print("Model path does not exist, skipping...")
    else:
        print("Model path is None - Nothing to restore")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager execution in TensorFlow encourages encapsulating model state in objects, for example in `tf.keras.Model` objects. The state of these objects (the "checkpointed" values of variables) can then be saved and restored using [`tf.contrib.eager.Checkpoint`](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/eager#object-based_saving)

Note that the `tf.contrib.eager.Checkpoint` class is compatible with both eager and graph execution.

You'll see this used in examples in the tensorflow repository such as [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/8753e2ebde6c58b56675cc19ab7ff83072824a62/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/examples/rnn_ptb/rnn_ptb.py#L326) and [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/3bdc47736aac1023da4b9929691849e06ab41ceb/official/mnist/mnist_eager.py#L141)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - yes I ended up encapsulating my model within a `tf.keras.Model` finally myself.

Comment: There is a tf.contrib.eager.Saver class too. Is any repository showing working code for it?  Are we supposed to combine tfe.Checkpoint and tfe.Saver some how? What exactly goes in the list to tfe.Saver when saving a tf.keras.Model object?